# Firebase Auth Admin C# SDK: How can I pre-create Auth Users for signin with the microsoft provider, using C# Admin SDK?

Tags: c#, firebase-authentication

I would like to pre-create or update users in the Firebase Auth by linking them to Microsoft Provider, using the C# Admin SDK.

I have looked at the official documentation and found no way to link Microsoft Provider to a user through C# Admin SDK.

Help, please!

I have created users with `CreateUserAsync` but `UserRecordArgs` has no options to link the user to Microsoft Provider.